# Iterating through collection based on index

Tags: c#, collections, iteration

Let me explain the situation first:

I receive a value from my Binary Search on a collection, and quickly jump to that to do some coding. Next I want to jump to the next item in the list. But this next item is not exactly the one that follows it could be 3 or 4 items later. Here is my data to understand the sitatuion

```
    Time          ID
    0604          ABCDE
    0604          EFGH
    0604          IJKL
    0626          Some Data1
    0626          Some Data2
    0626          Some Data3
    0626          Some Data4
```

Let's say Binary search return's index 0, I jump to index 0 (0604   ABCDE). I process/consume all 0604. Now I am at index 0, how do I jump to index 3 (0626) and consume / process all of it. Keeping in mind this will not always be the same. Data can be different. So I can't simply jump : `index + 3`

Here's my code:

```
 var matches = recordList.Where(d => d.DateDetails == oldPointer);
 var lookup = matches.ToLookup(d => d.DateDetails).First();
 tempList = lookup.ToList();// build templist
```

`oldPointer` here is the index I get from Binary search. I take this up and build a templist. Now after this I want to jump to 0626.

Comment: Your list is a data container, it shouldn't be part of your work flow, it is part of you to design that. I can't see any correlation here that links item 0 to item 3 other than the difference in times? but then there are 4 different 0626's so how do you know which to jump to? **edit**: I notice you are processing them all anyway so why do you need to jump at all?

Comment: what is your collection is it a diccionary, and what are the rules of your jumping mate

Comment: Please check my current code, I'm takin the binarysearch index into a templist to consume this data somewhere. Now I want to jump to 0626. How is this possible.

Comment: what is the purpose of `lookup` there? The `Where` tells us that all the `DateDetails` are the same, so doing a `ToLookup(...).First().ToList()` will just give us back: the same thing we had in `matches`...?

Comment: @user726720 you say you want to "jump to 0626"; but: what does that mean? do you actually know the "0626" somehow? or do you just want the next value that isn't `0604` (the current pointer)?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'm using the lookup for building the templist based on oldPointer

Comment: @MarcGravell:Yes you are correct I want the next value that may or maynot be 0626 (just used here for explanation)

Comment: @user726720 but... why? you've *already filtered* to a single `DateDetails` value. Doing a `ToLookup` on that will give you exactly 1 group (assuming at least one value) - the group that contains **all** the data that was in `matches`

Comment: @MarcGravell: I filtered this index (from binary search) into a group into a templist. Now I need to move to the next set of group, to use it somewhere else.

Comment: @user726720 by definition, your temp list doesn't contain the next item, and therefore doesn't help us. Note that `Where`, a `ToLookup`, and `ToList` are really pretty expensive here (**especially** the where, since that iterates the entire source collection). Frankly: it would be more efficient to just walk forwards in the data until you get a different value.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Recordlist contains my complete data. From this recordlist I'm doing a binary search, based on Index I jump to this record, move it to a templist to use it. Next I want the next set of group not into the templist but just as an index to use this index in my code.

Comment: That's a **really, really** expensive way to build the temp list, unless the data is trivially small; and if it is trivially small, it is irrelevant. The temp list does not really help you here, unless you simply mean: `index += tempList.Count;`

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes that's what I mean. Oh boy my bad day today, couldn't think of such a small thing. Hats off to you. +1 for that. Discussions make things easier. Thank you for that.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Kindly please post this as an answer so I may accept this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many records with the same "old pointer" do you typically expect? Is usually going to be less than 100? if so: don't over-complicate it - just iterate:

```
public static int FindNextPointerIndex(int oldIndex, string oldPointer, ...)
{
    for(int i = oldIndex + 1; i < collection.Count ; i++)
    {
        if(collection[i].DateDetails != oldPointer) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If you want something more elegant, you will have to pre-index the data by `DateDetails`, presumably using something like a `ToLookup` over the entire collection, but: note that this makes changes to the data more complicated.

Comment: can you explain your second point in terms of code. Thank you

Comment: @user726720 which bit, exactly? What I am saying is that there are ways of building an object model that would allow effective movement over large collections, but frankly: since you just want the "next different value": *just walk forwards until you find it*. If the size is huge and the could be lots and lots of one value, you could actually do a binary search between the current position and the end of the collection.

Comment: Binary Search here won't help because I don't know whats the next value.

Comment: maybe you could be right simple manually iterate and find the index of next different value. If you can explain your last point. Doing a tolookup over the entire collection. Can this be done to find the next group. How will this implemented in terms of code.

Comment: @user726720 you **wouldn't** do that, unless the grouping already existed for other purposes...

Comment: THanks mate I accept your answer. You tempted me for the discussion and gave me the solution in the comments above, kindly put that as part your solution. THank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Skip List , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

It will allow you to jump forward more than 1 in your linked list, but the down side to find the start of your search will be O(n)